# Expose a virtual host with ngrok

Tags: virtualhost, ngrok

I understand you can expose a virtual url such as `local.dev` using `ngrok http -host-header=local.dev`.

However I can't seem to expose a virtual host of the following format `sub.local.dev`. If I enter the ngrok command: `ngrok http -host-header=sub.local.dev` it just looks forwards the following url which does not exist: `http://.local.dev:80`.

Please tell me there is some way to do this

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out. It was a simple fix but it's not very clear in the documentation. I should have been using the following format: `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite local.globalnews.ca`